# difference between docker BRIDGE and HOST driver?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

Can you give me one guide or graph to understand the difference?

The reason why I ask this question is I can't open website with the following method:

```
docker network create -d bridge mybridge 
docker run -d --net mybridge --name db redis 
docker run -d --net mybridge -e DB=db -p 8000:5000 --name web chrch/web
```

But I can open website with the following method:

```
docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx
```

I use google cloud platform VM instance and install docker by myself.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the [docker documentation about bridge networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/):

> In terms of Docker, a bridge network uses a software bridge which allows containers connected to the same bridge network to communicate, while providing isolation from containers which are not connected to that bridge network.

According to the [docker documentation about host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

> If you use the host network driver for a container, that container’s network stack is not isolated from the Docker host. For instance, if you run a container which binds to port 80 and you use host networking, the container’s application will be available on port 80 on the host’s IP address.

If you want to deploy multiple containers connected between them with a private internal network use bridge networking. If you want to deploy a container connected to the same network stack as the host (and access the same networks as the host) use host networking. If you simply want to [publish some ports](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports), run the container with the `--publish` or `-p` option, such as `-p 8080:80`.

Comment: what about host firewall rules? is host behind firewall and bridge is not, or vice versa, or both ignore host firewall

Answer (score 14):

In your first example I'd expect the application to be reachable on the host's IP address at port 8000 (the remapped port), and in the second port 5000 (there is no remapping option with host networking).  If there's some sort of configuration or firewalling issue preventing this from working you should address that, rather than hack around it with `--net host`.

---

Bridge networking is Docker's standard networking mode.  You should prefer it if at all possible.  There are, confusingly, two different modes of it, but the form you show with an explicit `docker network create` is a best practice and you should use it if at all possible.  Host networking completely disables Docker's network isolation.  It means containers see and use exactly the same network interfaces the host has available, without an intermediate NAT layer.

With bridge networking, you need the `docker run -p` option to make specific ports visible outside of Docker.  As an operator you can remap ports, bind to specific interfaces on a multi-homed system, or simply decline to make a service visible to other hosts at all.  The explicit `docker network create` form lets containers connect to each other using their `docker run --name` as host names.  If you're running multiple application stacks on the same host, they can be partially isolated from each other by using separate networks.  Each container has its own separate network space, and `localhost` means "this container".  This mode is also an easy step to the networking models in multi-host systems like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes.

With host networking, none of the above works at all; you cannot use `docker run --net host -p ...` and you have no choice about where or how ports are exposed.  You can't reach other containers, unless they're configured to publish ports themselves.  Since you're using the host's network, `localhost` means the host's view of itself.

For all that it's frequently recommended in SO answers, `--net host` is rarely necessary.  The two cases I can think of off hand are for a service that needs to interrogate the host's network stack (for instance, a service-discovery system like Consul needs to know every port the host is listening on to advertise that) or for a service that has a large or inconsistent set of ports it uses.  If you're using `--net host` because you've hard-coded `localhost` in your application, you're better off making that configurable..

Answer (score 2):

| `Feature` | `Bridge` | `Host` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Driver** | The Bridge network is provided by the Bridge driver | The host network is provided by the host driver. |
| **Default** | bridge is the default network and provided by a bridge driver | Host does not default. |
| **Connectivity** | The bridge driver provides intercontainer connectivity for all containers running on the same machine. | The host driver instructs Docker not to create any special networking namespace or resources for attached containers. |